# Terraform custom provider - Error asking for user input

Tags: terraform

I am quite new to terraform and golang, I am trying to implement a custom provider, for a POC, to check if we can leverage terraform for our own use.

I was able to write and build the golang provider according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BvpqmFpchI) video and some GitHub examples.

I created a go workspace an set the $GOPATH to default, $HOME/go.

Terraform packages is installed at $GOPATH/src/github/hashicorp.

Terraform binary is installed at $HOME/dev and specified at the $PATH.

according to the video, I created the provider package at /terraform/builtin/providers/mycustomprovider

And "go build"ed the package to $GOPATH/bin

Once I tried to ***'terraform plan'*** I get the following:

> provider.incapsula: no suitable version installed
>
> version requirements: "(any version)"
>
> versions installed: none

I added the custom provider binary to terraform.d/plugins and tried to run 'terraform plan' again.

now I am getting the following error:

> Error: Error asking for user input: 1 error(s) occurred:
>   * provider.incapsula: fork/exec ~/.terraform.d/plugins/darwin_amd64/terraform-provider-incapsula: permission denied

I tried to chmod to 666 and chown the binary file, but with no luck, I am still getting the same error.

I tried to look for this kind of issue but couldn't find any reference.

I would appreciate any assistance.

Thanks!

Comment: can you active debug mode, and try again, anything helpful? `TF_LOG=DEBUG terraform plan`

Answer (score 5):

The provider binary needs execute permissions, so try using 755 instead of 666. Also if the binary isn't somewhere in your `$PATH`, you generally need to run `terraform init -plugin-dir=.terraform/plugins/darwin_amd64" so terraform picks up the provider and updates the md5 lock file.

So try `chmod 755 <wherever the provider is>` and if it's still not working, use `terraform init` with the `-plugin-dir` argument pointing to the plugin directory (your provider should already be in there).